# Why dataframe looping is not working with columns

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe named as df_tag. To preprocess the data, I go through the dataframe column wise in a for loop. In the else case, I have a String column, that first transforms the strings to lower case (#lower) and second applies a lambda function with regex (#punctuation). Problem is that in a for-loop the punctuation-part does not work:

```
for col in df_tag.columns:
    if df_tag[col].dtypes == "int64":
        new_data[col]=df_tag[col]
    else:
        #lower
        new_data[col] = df_tag[col].str.lower()        
        #punctuation
        new_data[col] = df_tag[col].apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))
```

But when I apply the punctuation-part without the for-loop it works fine. Here is an example where I apply this on the explicitly called column 'Name':

```
new_data['Name'] = df_tag['Name'].apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))
```

Can anyone give me the good way for looping with columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-loop solution you are replacing your lower-part with punctuation-part in new_data[col]

Will give you an example how to make your code work:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'Col1':list(range(1,5)),'Col2': list(range(6,10)),'Col3': ['a=b~c','B-C-D','c?d?e','D.E,F'] }
df_tag = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
print(df_tag)
#   Col1  Col2   Col3
#0     1     6  a=b~c
#1     2     7  B-C-D
#2     3     8  c?d?e
#3     4     9  D.E,F
```

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df_tag)
for col in df_tag.columns:
    if df_tag[col].dtypes == "int64":
        new_data[col]=df_tag[col]
    else:
        #lower & punctuation
        new_data[col] = df_tag[col].str.lower().apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))
```

and print of result will look like this

```
print(new_data)
#   Col1  Col2   Col3
#0     1     6  a b c
#1     2     7  b c d
#2     3     8  c d e
#3     4     9  d e f
```

Comment: well working but for df_tag[col].apply(lambda x: lammatizer.lemmatize(x))     this also i need to do with lower,punctuation

Comment: then maybe do like this in your else part: **1.** transformation (#lower) and store in new_data[col] `new_data[col] = df_tag[col].str.lower()`, **2.** another transformation based on new_data[col] `new_data[col] = new_data[col].apply(lambda x: ...)` and then **3.** transformation (#punctuation) `new_data[col] = new_data[col].apply(lambda x : " ".join(re.findall('[\w]+',x)))`, and so on if you have more transformations ...

Comment: check wheather your answer is my question.i have some more transformations like that